# How to execute an optional value although the found value is nil?

Tags: swift

So I've read the Wiki and related threads about optionals and force unwrapping, but I have the following problem. I'm doing the tutorial 'Start developing iOS' in which you build a small 'FoodTracker' app.

I've been getting the before mentioned error (Thread 1: Fatal Error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value). So I thought I would just make it a non-forced execution, but when I do this the cells (an image, a title and a star rating) come back empty. So the app will build and run, but the three examples aren't displayed.

When I make the cell.nameLabel.text = meal.name a comment, the error shifts to the next string (about the image).

It feels a bit like the app can't find the examples the tutorial lets you implement, 'sees nil' and returns an error..

Thanks you!

```
import UIKit
class MealTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //MARK: Properties

    var meals = [Meal]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Load the sample data.
        loadSampleMeals()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: - Table view data source


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return meals.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MealTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MealTableViewCell.")
        }

        // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
        let meal = meals[indexPath.row]

        **cell.nameLabel.text = meal.name          (ERROR is here)
        cell.photoImageView.image = meal.photo
        cell.ratingControl.rating = meal.rating**

        return cell
    }

    //MARK: Private Methods

    private func loadSampleMeals() {

        let photo1 = UIImage(named: "meal1")
        let photo2 = UIImage(named: "meal2")
        let photo3 = UIImage(named: "meal3")

        guard let meal1 = Meal(name: "Caprese Salad", photo: photo1, rating: 4) else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal1")
        }

        guard let meal2 = Meal(name: "Chicken and Potatoes", photo: photo2, rating: 5) else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal2")
        }

        guard let meal3 = Meal(name: "Pasta with Meatballs", photo: photo3, rating: 3) else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal3")
        }

        meals += [meal1, meal2, meal3]
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have your image in assets.xcassets ?

Comment: Connect the `nameLabel` `IBOutlet` (and the other outlets) in the custom cell in Interface Builder

Comment: Hi Vadian, thank you for the suggestion. I'm going to try and report back :) Titouan the images are indeed in the correct folder. The problem actualy shifts so it looks like a layer above (kinda thing..)

Comment: So in the MealTableViewCell.swift are the three @IBOutlet lines present but the connection is not present (a white dot instead of a grey filled dot). SO you are certainly on the right track. I'll try to figure out how to connect the custom cell in IB. :)

Comment: If you create the outlets **exactly** [as described in the tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW10) then the outlets are connected.

Comment: Vadian, you did it! Thanks a million!